# recursion function call doesn't work as expected

Tags: php

Im trying the login with twitter functionality.

if twitter returned username already exist in my database I am creating a new username for that user.

following is my code

```
class myclass{
    function getusername($username){
        global $db;
        $sql ="select * from us_signup where username ='".$username."'";
        echo $sql;
        $results = $db->rawQuery($sql);     

        if(!empty($results)){
        echo 'if';
        print_r($username);
            $username = $username.rand(0,1000);
            $this->getusername($username);
        }else{
        echo "else";
        print_r($username);
            return $username;
        }
    }

    function insertintodb(){
        echo "oldusername : ".$username;
        $username = $this->getusername($username);
        echo "newusername : ". $username;   
    }

}
```

1) `insertintodb` calls getusername with currentusername got from twitter

2) `getusername` checks it in the database

3) if the username exist in the database then it adds a random number to it and then calls itself

4) if the username doesn't exist in the database it returns the username

5) `getusername` calls itself until it finds username which doesn't exist in the database

**My problem is**

I am calling the function `getusername` with 'sugumar' which exist in the database
so it calls itself again with `newusername` 'sugumar1234'(1234 is a random number can be anynumber). 'sugumar1234' doesn't exist in the database so I expect it return 'sugumar1234' but it returns nothing

following the ouput of print

> oldusername : sugumarselect * from us_signup where username
>   ='sugumar'ifsugumarselect * from us_signup where username ='1234'else1234newusername :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, a `return` statement seems to be missing in the `if` part of your code.

```
$this->getusername('1234');
```

Should be

```
return $this->getusername('1234');
```

Comment: if you don't mind could you please explain why should I need return... because I really don't understand....

Comment: When you call `getUserName` with `sugumar` parameter, this name exists in the database, therefore, the function `getUserName` calls itself with a new (randomized) parameter, this time the new paremeter (let's say `foo`) does not exist in the database, so it's returned by `return $username;` statement. However, this returned value is not affected to any variable nor returned in the first `getUserName` call (the one with `sugumar` parameter), therefore it's lost and the function does not return anything. Not sure if I'm clear, if not, I may make a scheme.